# SSIS Execute SQL task not updating although breakpoint displays correct sql statement in variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, ssis, bids

My `SSIS` package has an an `Execute SQL Task` object that runs at the very end of the package, where `SqlStatementSourceType = Variable`, and `SqlStatementSource = User::UpdateSql`.

I've set a breakpoint in `Break when the container receives the OnPreExecute event`; variable `User::UpdateSql` equals `UPDATE dbo.TableReportSummary set FileDate =   'C:\\FILES\\Files\\Ssis\\TextFiles\\THIS_IS_A_SIMPLE_TEST_090215.txt'`

During package execution, everything runs correctly. But I check `[TableReportSummary]` and `FileDate` equals `null`.

My question is, why isn't it updating correctly? If an error had been encountered with the UPDATE (ie. connection problems, sql syntax, etc), the step would have failed.

I can copy/paste that exact UPDATE statement into a sql server editor, and the update is done correctly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To restate: you have an `OnPreExecute` breakpoint set on an Execute SQL Task. When the breakpoint is hit, you inspect the database and the command has not fired. Running the same command in a query window results in the statement actually firing.

Comment: Not exactly. When the `OnPreExecute` breakpoint  is hit, I check to see that the  variable has the correct t-sql update, and it's correct. After the `Execute SQL Task` is completed, I check the database, and the column has NULL as values. So, either the update was not executed, or it was executed incorrectly. Either way, the task (and package) runs successfully.

Comment: So much for the easy answer of Pre vs Post Execute ;) The variable `User::UpdateSql` is being built/modified during the execution, yes? When you are looking at the value during run-time, are you using the Locals Window and then expanding the Variables collection and finding it or are you looking at the Variables window? The former shows you the run-time value while the latter is the the design-time value. Are you certain the connection manager is pointed to the correct location for the Execute SQL Task. What if you turn on profiler on that server, do you see the Execute SQL Task firing? Trxns?

Comment: Everything's correct. Apparently the problem was the order of the objects in the package. I'm not sure why that would be an issue, since they were all marked green when they ran and the breakpoint displayed the correct UPDATE in the variable just before executing the SQL object. Anyways, now they're all sequential (one after the other) and it works fine.